# Unable to build a cpp program on AIX with gcc fsanitize address

Tags: gcc, aix, clang

I'm trying to build a cpp program on AIX 7.2 using gcc with address sanitizer (`-fsanitize=address`) but this errors out with:

```
cc1plus: warning: '-fsanitize=address' not supported for this target
collect2: fatal error: library libasan not found
compilation terminated.
```

I thought maybe the compilation will succeed if I have the `libasan` shared library. So I tried building `llvm` from source but running into the same issue with that:

```
> export CC=gcc; export CXX=g++;
> cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS=clang -DLLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES=compiler-rt -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/llvm_install -DLLVM_USE_SANITIZER=Address -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="PowerPC" -G "Unix Makefiles" /llvm-project/llvm
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target LLVMDemangle
[  0%] Building CXX object lib/Demangle/CMakeFiles/LLVMDemangle.dir/Demangle.cpp.o
cc1plus: error: '-fsanitize=address' not supported for this target [-Werror]
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

My environment:

```
gcc version 10.3.0
cmake version 3.20.0
AIX 7.2
```

**Questions:**

1. Does gcc not support `fsanitize=address` on AIX?
2. Has someone successfully built a cpp program with address sanitizer
   on AIX? If so, can you please share the steps.
3. Do I need to use [xlc](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/xl-c-and-cpp-aix/16.1?topic=new-clang-based-front-end)? Is there no way to make this work with `gcc`?

Apologies if this it not the right forum to ask AIX queries.

Comment: I think your 1. question is quite explicitly answered by the output you've gotten.

Comment: I had to work in an AIX environment 10 yrs ago, and I found there was more "native" AIX users on ittoolbox.com. You have to register as a user, and then find/join the AIX specific "forum" (this may all be different now). Later I discovered there are (even better) support forums under ibm.com, and was able to find what I needed without posting a question.

Comment: If your program works with libasan, then it will work without it as well.